# finding the MAX number of characters in the list : Python code

Tags: python, string, sage

i have written the bellow code and i need to get the MAX number of characters from the list it gives.

```
def ssin(a):
    ASAS = map(lambda y: (chr(ord('A')+y),len(filter(lambda x: ord(x) - ord('A') == y, a))),range(0,26))
    return ASAS

ssin('THE AGES OF THE KINGS')
```

answer:

```
[('A', 1), ('B', 0), ('C', 0), ('D', 0), ('E', 3), ('F', 1), ('G', 2),
('H', 2), ('I', 1), ('J', 0), ('K', 1), ('L', 0), ('M', 0), ('N', 1),
('O', 1), ('P', 0), ('Q', 0), ('R', 0), ('S', 2), ('T', 2), ('U', 0),
('V', 0), ('W', 0), ('X', 0), ('Y', 0), ('Z', 0)]
```

how to find the MAX number of characters in a given string?

Comment: Is this for a homework assignment? If so, please add the tag `homework` to the question.

Answer (score 2):

`Counter` is your friend:

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> Counter(char.upper() for char in 'THE AGES OF THE KINGS' if char.isalpha()).most_common(1)
[('E', 3)]
```

Comment: well mate i have to use SAGE...... and have to use the above code. thats the problemo!

Comment: One possible difficulty (apart from tiebreaking): I notice that the OP added the "Sage" tag.  Released Sage is based on python 2.6, and doesn't have Counter in collections.

Answer (score 0):

Your function is painful to the eye, but if you can use this to find the most frequent value:

```
sorted(ssin('THE AGES OF THE KINGS'), key = itemgetter(1), reverse = True)[0]
```

That doesn't do anything to check whether or not there are ties for the most frequent.

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> import operator
>>> freqinfo = ssin('THE AGES OF THE KINGS')
>>> max(freqinfo,key=operator.itemgetter(1))
('E',3)
```

Basically `max(freqinfo,key=operator.itemgetter(1))` says "look for the object in `freqinfo` for which the freqinfo[i][1] is maximum". Because `freqinfo[i]` is a `(letter,frequency)` pair.

Comment: 'def ssin(a):
    maxv = 0
    ASAS = map(lambda y: (chr(ord('A')+y),len(filter(lambda x: ord(x) - ord('A') == y, a))),range(0,26))'
    return max(ASAS, key=lambda item: item[1])


    
    
ssin('ADFGHSDFHGSDFGAGFDADSFGSADFGAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA')